# Is there a good MSSQL / SQL Server adapter for sails.js?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, sql-server-2008, node.js, sails.js

I want to preface this with saying that I really like sails.js for a simple MVC framework, but feel that it lacks in its documentation and api reference.

I searched all over to try and find any information on a **good mssql (SQL server) adapter for Sails.js**, but cannot find one. I am hoping someone has come across one, and could recommend it. I also looked into building a custom adapter, but found the documentation to not be helpful. Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now: https://github.com/cnect/sails-sqlserver

Complete with sails 0.10 associations support, and fully unit tested against the Waterline spec:

Comment: Nice, I took a quick peek at the code in the lib, but have not yet tested it out. Just looking at the code, it looks nice. I saw Stuart has also started one a while back, and then ended up contributing to your repo. Since this is a more complete adapter, I will mark this answer :)

Answer (score 3):

We don't currently have a MS SQL Server adapter but it's something I'd love to add. There is a basic definition of the various interfaces and how adapters are created at: [API Adapter Interface](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-wiki/blob/0.9/api.adapter-interface.md).

If anyone would like to tackle this you can use the [Sails MySQL Adapter](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql) or the [Sails PostgreSQL Adapter](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-postgresql) as examples.

I don't have access to a MS SQL Server to build one out but there is an Integration Test library I use to build out adapters that support the CRUD interface: [Waterline Adapter Tests](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-adapter-tests).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The docs page link helps. I have already started an adapter, but barely have time to work on it. Hopefully I will have some free time in the near future to make something basic where others can expand on it, or someone else makes something. I know Microsoft is not popular among the open source communities, but thats okay

Comment: Note from the future: There exists an officially-supported sails.js SQL Server adapter: **https://github.com/cnect/sails-sqlserver**

Answer (score 3):

I have recently started building a sails adapter for MSSQL based on the node-sqlserver module.

It isn't finished yet but I have finished the main parts of the adapter and it still needs testing, but there is enough there to get going.

It can be found at https://github.com/swelham/sails-mssql

Answer (score 0):

Technically since Sails is base on express.js you could use custom express middleware to specify the use of your an adapter that has already been created.

The first one is the top rated adapter
checkout https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/mysql

Otherwise you can just use the waterline ORM and the MySQL adapter that is provided for sails.js

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql

For documentation on how to use waterline models checkout the 0.9x docuemntation
http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was primarily asking about SQL Server / TDS (Microsoft) not MySQl. I found many great modules for MySQL and Sails has an adapter for it as well. I was just hoping there was an SQL Server adapter for sails already in existence so that I would not have to create my own adapter.

Answer (score 0):

sails-mssql is working fine for me on 0.10.x, here's a gist of how to configure it, using sails-mssql 0.10.x

https://gist.github.com/hybrisCole/868f979d8d129247a2da

my package.json has this:
"sails-mssql": "git://github.com/jaredfromsubway/sails-mssql.git#master",

Answer (score 0):

[Sails-sql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-sql) is currently the latest adapter for MySQL/MSSQL (eventually PostgreSQL as well). It's currently safe, fine-tuned, and upgraded for use in production with MySQL and MSSQL. Most developments are primarily pending for PostgreSQL at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Another current option is https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mssql 
(https://github.com/intel/sails-mssql).